# Arduino/c++ - Passing PROGMEM string to class using F() Macro

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

Ive done some googling and I cant find a solution to my problem.  Im not sure if Im attempting to use the F() macro improperly in c++ or if I misunderstand something fundamental.

The arduino IDE includes a library WString.h which has some macros and other functions which help with placing strings in PROGMEM rather than SRAM.

I am attempting to create a class which contains a pointer to a string in PROGMEM which is passed using the F() macro.

I created a small example program to test this.  This program creates a new instance of a test class whose whole purpose is to print out PROGMEM string.

```
class FTester{
  private:
    const __FlashStringHelper* Label;

  public:
    FTester(const __FlashStringHelper* _Label): Label(_Label){};
    void print(){ Serial.println(Label); };
};
```

My main program then simply creates a new instance of my class, and calls the print function:

```
FTester FS(F("FString-TestingTesting123"));

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  FS.print();
}
```

This code does not compile and I get the following error:

```
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28:0,
                 from sketch\FTester.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/WString.h:38:74: error: statement-expressions are not allowed outside functions nor in template-argument lists
 #define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))
                                                                          ^
C:\Users\Nick1\Desktop\FTester\FTester.ino:11:12: note: in expansion of macro 'F'
 FTester FS(F("FString-TestingTesting123"));
            ^

exit status 1
```

One thing that stood out to me was the part of the error which says "not allowed outside functions nor in template-argument lists".

Is this related to the fact that Im using the F() macro inside of a constructor or the fact that Im using list initializers?  My class is not a template so Im not sure if the "template-argument lists" part is applicable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PROGMEM directly. The `F()` macro is code that requires a function.

You can then cast the char pointer to a `__FlashStringHelper*` when needed.

```
class FTester{
  private:
    const char* Label;

  public:
    FTester( const char *pstr ): Label(pstr){};
    void print(){ Serial.println( (const __FlashStringHelper*) Label ); };
};


const char str[] PROGMEM = "FString-TestingTesting123";

FTester FS(str);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  FS.print();
}
```

### EDIT:

Oh, and the above is how you could do it if `FS` is a global variable, like your example. If it was a local variable, the `F()` macro could be used.

```
 class FTester{
  private:
    const __FlashStringHelper* Label;

  public:
    FTester( const __FlashStringHelper* pstr ): Label(pstr){};
    void print(){ Serial.println( Label ); };
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  FTester FS(F("FString-TestingTesting123"));
  FS.print();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Awesome thanks for your help.  It turns out the way I want my code written Im using global variables.  I also want to pass the string as an argment rather than defining a separate variable.

I ended up taking a different approach where I store the information into PROGMEM in the object constructor.  This has the needed effect of storing the data into PROGMEM and saving SRAM.

```
class FTester{
  private:
    const char* Label PROGMEM;

  public:
    FTester(const char* _Label): Label(_Label){};
    void print(){ Serial.println(Label); };
};

FTester FS("FString-TestingTesting123");

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  FS.print();
}
```

Comment: That is not doing what you think. You are only storing a pointer in the class, not the string data. And as its not a static member, it is not going to be in flash. You need to do it similar to what I have done in my answer.

You can see this is true as `Serial.println(Label)` is printing a `char*` not a `__FlashStringHelper*`.

Comment: My goal at the end of the day is to make sure the string is stored in PROGMEM instead of flash. I realized this was a pointer I was storing and I thought it was a pointer to PROGMEM where the string was being stored.  I think i understand what your saying that the string is still in SRAM but I only put the poiner to the string in PROGMEM? I tested my solution and it prints out "FString-TestingTesting123" as expected.

Comment: I will work, but not as expected. Neither the String or the pointer to it is in Flash. You can see this is the case as the call to `Serial.println(Label)` is not using the `println()` which prints PROGMEM data. It is simply printing out your RAM string.